# Kendo grid change event fires only once per row selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In a MVC4 project, I've got a kendo grid that fires an event when a row is selected.

```
<div id="datagrid">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SustIMS.Models.StretchModel>()
    .Name("datagrid_Stretches")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(s => s.StretchCode).Title(ViewBag.lblCode).Width(80);
        columns.Bound(s => s.StretchMediumDescription).Title(ViewBag.lblDescription);
        ...
    })
    .Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))    <--------- here's the event
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(15)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetStretches", "MasterData"))
    )
)
</div>
```

So, when I select a row, the `onChange` function is called:

```
function onChange() {
    var code = this.dataItem(this.select()).StretchCode;
    $.get('@Url.Content("getStretchCode")',
        { "code": code });
}
```

In my controller, the code is retrieved and some operations are done with it.

```
public void getStretchCode(string code)
{
    currentStretch.RoadComponentCode = code;
    ...
}
```

This works fine. The problem is, the event is fired every time I select a different row but if I select a row that was previously selected, the event isn't fired and I can't get the code of that row.

Any help?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more details may be a sample jsbin of your code, because it fires each time. Please have a look at this link: http://dojo.telerik.com/@NitinMall/Axap

Comment: I don't know, as you can see the grid is Razor HTML helper code. The grid doesn't show in jsbin

Comment: The event fires when the row selection __changes__. Selecting the same row that's already selected changes nothing, so no event is fired.

Comment: @Brett, you must have misunderstood. Picture this: I select `row1` -> the event fires and gives me `id=1`; I select `row2` -> the event fires and gives me `id=2`; I select `row1` again -> the event isn't fired and the id remains `id=2`. It's not "selecting the same row that's already selected", as you said, but a row that has been selected before. Can you help?

Comment: Did you forget to define the grid as `.Selectable()`?

Comment: @Brett, the grid is `.Selectable()` otherwise I couldn't select rows at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.Selectable()` in your grid so it allow you select previously row.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SustIMS.Models.StretchModel>()
    .Name("datagrid_Stretches")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(s => s.StretchCode).Title(ViewBag.lblCode).Width(80);
        columns.Bound(s => s.StretchMediumDescription).Title(ViewBag.lblDescription);
        ...
    })
 .Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Type(GridSelectionType.Row)  <--------- Add This
            )
    .Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))    
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(15)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetStretches", "MasterData"))
    )
)
```

**Script**

```
function onChange() {
    var code = this.dataItem(this.select()).StretchCode;
    $.post('@Url.Content("getStretchCode")',
        { "code": code });
}
```

Comment: Isn't just `Selectable()` enough? **Edit**: I'm sorry but it didn't work, it still doesn't fire the event. I already had `Selectable()` without the `GridSelectionType` but neither of them works

Comment: yes `.selectable()` is enough. I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: @chiapa see this Demo: http://jsbin.com/honavive/4/edit ,

it's working perfectly fine here.

Comment: Yes, it works there but I'm using Razor html helper and not javascript, maybe that's the problem? Or is the problem in my javascript `onChange()` function? Would you mind checking it? Try to alter your `onChange` function to show the alert box but with the selected row id

Comment: @chiapa yes i know i am using Razor to. But for example i am using java script. it's working fine in my razor syntax.

Comment: @chiapa post you full Grid and Script function. So i see your code and let you know where is problem is any there.

Comment: @chiapa i already look into your question and i am working on that.

Answer (score 2):

you should add Selectable()  before add event like this

```
 .Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
            .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
.Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
```

Comment: You mean `.Events(events => events.DataBound("onChange"))`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately, it doesn't work. The issue remains

Comment: did you add these code ?
.Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
            .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))

Comment: we also use kendo grid but didint get problem like this we only use Selectable keyword

Comment: ohh is this only problem with IE ?

Comment: The problem was in the javascript function: by changing `$.get` to `$.post`, it now works fine. **edit**: no, the IE issue is in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883572/javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-in-interne) - I'm sorry, I posted that by accident!

Comment: ohh you passing value with $.get