# Reload Kendo Grid, not just the data in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid: how can I reload the whole grid after clicking a button? Here's the button:

```
<input type="button" id="btnReload" name="reload" value="Reload" />
```

Below is the function that handles the button click:

```
$('#btnReload').click(function (e) {
    var grid = $("#datagrid_Roads").data("kendoGrid");
    //grid.reload();
    grid.dataSource.page(1);
    grid.dataSource.read();
});
```

OK, the above refreshes the data in the grid. What I want is something like the commented code (in the above block) so the whole grid is reloaded, not just the data in it.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

The reason I want this is because I want to make a custom filter to my grid since the built-in filter functionalities of the grid do not work for me in Internet Explorer, as can be seen in [this question I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883572/javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-in-interne/25035689?noredirect=1#comment38940939_25035689) to which I **still haven't found** a solution. The custom filter is a `DropDownList` with different values for filtering. (in my case, concessions to which the listed roads belong)

Here are the grid specifications:

```
<div id="datagrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SustIMS.Models.RoadModel>()
        .Name("datagrid_Roads")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(r => r.RoadCode).Title(ViewBag.lblCode).Width(140);
            columns.Bound(r => r.RoadType).Title(ViewBag.RoadType).Width(140);
            ...
            columns.Bound(r => r.ConcessionMediumDescription).Title(ViewBag.Concession);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 534px;" })
        ...
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Filter(filters =>
            {
                filters.Add(road => road.ConcessionMediumDescription).Contains(Session["concessionFilter"].ToString());
            })
            .PageSize(15)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetRoads", "MasterData"))
        )
    )
</div>
```

As you can see, I set a filter that's a session variable, set as the first item of a `DropDownList` by default.

When the user changes the DropDownList selection, a controller method is called and the session variable is set with a filter value. However, the grid doesn't show any filtered data because it was loaded before with the previous value of the session variable. I want it to be reloaded with the new value for the session variable so the filter actually works.

Anyone?

Comment: here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid

Comment: Thanks @MohitArora, I've seen that and it doesn't work. It refreshes the data in the grid but not the grid itself. I want the grid to be completely erased and rebuilt. I'll add some more details to the question explaining why I want this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 $('#btnReload').click(function (e) {
  var grid = $("#datagrid_Roads").data("kendoGrid");         
  grid.dataSource.filter({});
  grid.dataSource.read();
  grid.refresh();
});
```

Comment: @chiapa you are filter your data from server side?

Comment: Not sure but I think it's server side

Comment: @chiapa it's your requirement or you don't know client side customize filtration.

Comment: No, it can be any filtering type, client or server side, I don't care.

Comment: @chiapa I don't know about server side filter but in client side filter it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: @chiapa It's working perfectly fine  for me also in serverside filtering.